# Tutorial Java para leitura de Certificado Digital A3

Tags: java, certificado-digital

Estou procurando um tutorial para implementação da leitura de cartões com certificado digital A3. Nunca trabalhei com nada parecido antes e agora surgiu essa necessidade.
Busquei algumas coisas na web e não encontrei nada parecido com uma receita de bolo, apenas algumas dúvidas já específicas, por exemplo:

- [Java x Certificado Digital (A3)](http://www.guj.com.br/11023-java-x-certificado-digital-a3)
- [Applet Java - Validar certificado digital A3](http://www.javac.com.br/jc/posts/list/955-applet-java-validar-certificado-digital-a3.page)

Alguem poderia me indicar algum material?

Comment: Desculpem por ressuscitar o tópico, mas é o seguinte, estamos com a necessidade aqui na empresa de enviar NFe a partir de certificados A3, e em uma aplicação web (JSF) sei que só tem como fazer isso com um Applet. Gostaria de saber se você conseguiu resolver o seu problema e se pode me ajudar?

Comment: Infelizmente não segui adiante com essa leitura pois o projeto em questão foi congelado, portanto, não atuei no problema.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Espero que esta documentação lhe ajude:

[Documentação Java x Certificados](http://devbrasil.net/group/nfce-em-java/page/como-o-java-trabalha-com-certificados-digitais)

Comment: Primeiramente desculpe pela demora para avaliar a resposta, acredito que o negativo que recebi foi justo. O código do seu link me ajudou bastante, é o melhor material até agora, assim que for possível eu voltar pra esse projeto, pretendo blogar sobre isso. Obrigado!